# Corrupted iPhone App after IOS 5 Upgrade

Tags: applications

Harraps Dictionary App is corrupt after IOS 5.0.  How do I restore it. I can see no way to download the App again through iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

It should still be in the purchased tab - you can check on a computer before you delete the corrupt version and re-download the latest version that was sold. I've been able to download many apps that are now no longer for sale so that seems to be the rule rather than the exception for apps that are no longer available for new purchasers.